# Probability of event not happening after exactly $k$ times.

Tags: probability

I believe I found the solution but would like a confirmation. The probability of a certain event $A$ happening is $0.375$. One way to calculate is the event not happening is to take the complement of $A$. So:
$$\bar{A} =1 - 0.375 = 0.625$$

If we wanted to find the probability of an event not happening after **exactly** (key word exactly) $k$, we can multiply $\bar{A}$, $k$ times then subtract our result from $1$.

For example, let us find the probability of event $A$ finally happening after exactly $8$ times.

$$0.625^8 \implies 0.0232 \implies 1 - 0.0232 \implies 0.9768 \implies 97.68\% $$

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

The probability of event $A$ happening after exactly $8$ failures is $.625^8(.375)$ (It has to fail 8 times in a row and then be a success)

There is a name for this, called the geometric distribution. Let $X\sim \text{Geometric}(.375)$ be the number of failures until success for $A$. Then $\Pr(X=x)=.675^x(.375), x=0,1,2,...$

To elaborate a little more, by the complement rule what you found via $1-.625^8$ is the probability that the $A$ occurs at least once in a series of $8$ trials.

Answer (score 1):

You have an event $A$ where the probability of A happening is $p$. As you say, the probability of the event $\bar A$ is $1-p$. You *independently* repeat trials of $A$ eight times, and you want to know the probability that A will fail 7 times and then succeed the eighth time. That would be:

$$
(1-p)^7p
$$
because $\bar A$ needs to happen 7 times and then $A$ needs to happen. Note that this is the same probability that you see $A$ once at all in eight trials.

$(1-0.375)^7(0.375) = 1.4\%$.